# Show the values of $x$ such that $g$ is continuous.

Tags: calculus, continuity, epsilon-delta, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

Let $g(x)$ be:

\begin{cases} 
     0 \space\space \text{if}\space\space x \in \mathbb Q \\
      x\space\space \text{if} \space\space x \in \mathbb R - \mathbb Q \\
   \end{cases}

That's what I've tried since I started:

If $g(x)$ is continuous so $\lim\limits_{x\to a}g(x) = g(a)$. By $\varepsilon - \delta$ definition:

$\forall \varepsilon \gt 0 \space \exists \delta \gt 0 \space\space$ such that $\space\space 0 \lt|x - a| \lt \delta \implies |g(x) - g(a)| \lt \varepsilon$.

First case: suppose $a \in \mathbb Q$ and $x \in \mathbb R - \mathbb Q$, so:

$|g(x) - g(a)| = |x - 0| = |x| \lt \varepsilon$.

Second case: suppose $a \in \mathbb R - \mathbb Q$ and $x \in \mathbb Q$, so:

$|g(x) - g(a)| = |0 - a| = |-a| = |a| \lt \varepsilon$.

It doesn't matter if $x$ and $a$ are greater or less than $0$. Considering I set both to be greater than $0$, $|x|$ and $|-a|$ and equal to $x$ and $a$ respectively, and, by definition, I can set $\varepsilon$ to be any number, so I can make it less than $x$ and less than $a$ at the same time, so the definition wouldn't hold. If they're negative, $|x|$ = $-x$ and $|-a| = -a$, I can also let $\varepsilon$ be any number such that it will be less than $-x$ and $-a$ simultaneously.

The only case where the definition would hold is when I set $a = 0$ in the first case, so it would be:

Given $\varepsilon \gt 0$ $\space$ $\exists \delta \gt 0$ $\space\space$ such that $\space\space$ $0 \lt |x - a| \lt \delta \implies |g(x) - g(a)| \lt \varepsilon$.

If $a = 0$ and $x$ remains a irrational number:

$0 \lt |x| \lt \delta$ $\implies$ $|x| \lt \varepsilon$. Let $\delta = \varepsilon$ and we conclude that g is continuous at $0$.

Is it enough? I've seen some proofs to this before, and they always used the Squeeze Theorem, I wanted to do this way because the approach they did seemed like a bit harder to visualize at the beginning.

Comment: " I've seen some proofs to this before, and they always used the Squeeze Theorem"  A hammer is a good tool but you don't need it to shovel snow.

Comment: The one I presented is a good one?

Comment: You should include a comment that for any interval around $a$ there will always be choices of rational and/or irrational $x$.  I'd word "First case: suppose a∈Q and x∈R−Q" as "First case: suppose $a \in \mathbb Q$.  Select an irrational $x$ so that $|x-a|< \delta$"  but that's stylistic.

Comment: Your idea of the proof is good.  Your execution and details need a little work.

Comment: Perfect. I'll make sure to improve that. Thank you!

Comment: Your proof of continuity at $0$ is okay except for only discussing $x$ being irrational. You need to show the inequality holds for all $|x-0| <\delta$, not just for irrational $x$.(Yes, rational $x$ is trivial, but you still need to include it, even if by nothing more than saying "when $x$ is rational, this is obvious". Your proof of discontinuity elsewhere is incomprehensible. To disprove, you negate everything in the definition.

Comment: Instead of showing $$\forall \varepsilon > 0,\exists \delta > 0,\forall x, |x-a| < \delta \implies |g(x) - g(a)| < \varepsilon$$ you need to show $$\exists \varepsilon > 0,\forall \delta > 0,\exists x, |x-a| < \delta \text{ and } |g(x) - g(a)| \ge \varepsilon$$ So start by picking a specific $\varepsilon$ (which may depend on $a$, but not $\delta$ or $x$) instead of discussing generic values. Then for any $\delta$, you also pick a specific $x$ (or show otherwise that there is always some value $x$ with $|x - a| < \delta$) such that $|g(x) - g(a)| \ge \varepsilon$ (show it, don't say it)